# React does not rerender instantly using setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this issue that I'm trying to fix, I have this piece of code that allows me to create a new blog:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import Blog from './components/Blog'
import Notification from './components/Notification'
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm'
import BlogForm from './components/BlogForm'
import Togglable from './components/Togglabe'
import blogService from './services/blogs'
import loginService from './services/login'
import './App.css'

const App = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([])
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null)
  const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(true)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const blogFormRef = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    blogService
      .getAll()
      .then(initialBlogs => {
        setBlogs(initialBlogs)
      })
  }, [])

  // ----- Add blog function ------
  const addBlog = async (blogObject) => {
    blogFormRef.current.toggleVisibility()
    const toAdd = blogService.createBlog(blogObject)
    const returned = await toAdd
    setBlogs(blogs.concat(returned))
  }

  // ----- Update Blog -----
  const updateBlog = async (id) => {
    const blog = blogs.find(blog => blog.id === id)
    const toUpdate = { ...blog, likes: blog.likes + 1 }
    const updateo = blogService.update(id, toUpdate)
    const returned = await updateo
    setBlogs(blogs.map(blog => blog.id !== id ? blog : returned))
  }

  // ----- Delete Blog -----
  const delBlog = async (id) => {
    const blogToDelete = blogService.deleteBlog(id)
    const deleted = await blogToDelete
    return deleted
  }

  // ----- Forms -------
  const blogForm = () => (
    <Togglable buttonLabel='new blog' ref={blogFormRef}>
      <BlogForm
        createBlog={addBlog}
      />
    </Togglable>
  )

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Blogs</h2>
      <Notification message={errorMessage}/>

      {user === null ?
        loginForm() :
        <div>
          <p>
            {user.name} logged-in
            <button onClick={(() => logOut())}>Log out</button>
          </p>
          {blogForm()}
        </div>
      }

      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setShowAll(!showAll)}>
          {showAll ? 'hide' : 'show'}
        </button>
      </div>

      <ul>
        {showAll === true ?
          blogs.map((blog, i) =>
            <Blog
              key={i}
              blog={blog}
              updateBlog={updateBlog}
              delBlog={delBlog} />
          )
          : null
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

and this other part is the form of the app that allows you to add a new blog

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const BlogForm = ({ createBlog }) => {
  const [newTitle, setNewTitle] = useState('')
  const [newAuthor, setNewAuthor] = useState('')
  const [newContent, setNewContent] = useState('')

  const handleTitle = (event) => {
    setNewTitle(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleAuthor = (event) => {
    setNewAuthor(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleContent = (event) => {
    setNewContent(event.target.value)
  }

  const addBlog = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    createBlog({
      title: newTitle,
      author: newAuthor,
      content: newContent,
      likes: 0
    })

    setNewTitle('')
    setNewAuthor('')
    setNewContent('')
  }

  return (
    <div className="formDiv">
      <form onSubmit={addBlog}>
        <div>
          <div>
            Title:
            <input
              id="title"
              type="text"
              value={newTitle}
              onChange={handleTitle}
            />
          </div>

          <div>
            Author:
            <input
              type="text"
              value={newAuthor}
              onChange={handleAuthor}
            />
          </div>

          <div>
            Content:
            <input
              type="text"
              value={newContent}
              onChange={handleContent}
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default BlogForm
```

So the problem is that I'm trying to add a new blog but it doesn't rerender the component and it doesn't show the new blog instantly. I have to refresh the page and then it appears. The funny thing is that it works with the updateBlog component which allows you to give a "LIKE" to some blog, but it doesn't react instantly with the AddBlog component.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? `const returned = await toAdd`

Comment: It is the promise returned from "const toAdd" variable, it is a axios POST request and "const returned: await toAdd" is the promise of that request. I keep it in the "returned" variable so i can modify the blog state

Comment: Weird - why not just `const returned = await blogService.createBlog(blogObject);` then?

Comment: yeah i made that change but still the `setBlogs(blogs.concat(returned))` doesn't rerender